# Powershell - Delete Folder Contents With Exclusions

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-4.0

I am trying to find a way to get a list of folders in a specific directory. The directories under the parent folder may contain subfolders themselves.  I would like to sort the folders that are directly under the parent folder based on the oldest last access time of any file in any of the subfolders of the parent folder.  Once I have the list of folders sorted correctly, I would like to begin deleting the files within the subfolders with a couple of exclusions.  There are a some files in the subfolders that I do not want deleted.  I would also like to keep a running count of the total size of files that have been deleted.  Once I reach a certain threshold with regards to the total size of files removed, I would like to exit out of the script.  Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a starting point but your criterias on what to keep are quite unclear

```
$MyRootFolderPath = "Your entry folder path"

Get-ChildItem -Path $MyRootFolderPath -Recurse | Where-Object {-not $_.PSIsContainer -and ($_.Name -notmatch "Your pattern to keep")} | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime | Select-Object -first 10 | Remove-Item
```